# Spring Kafka Streams: Type Information Missing

Tags: spring-kafka

I have setup a simple Spring Boot App with Kafka Streams. Spring boot is creating the factory using AutoConfiguration for Kafka. The message is a Json Message with no message key. Using the below config results in a No Type information in headers message. Any inputs?

```
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.value.serde=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.key.default.type=java.lang.String
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.abc.xyz.Person
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:353) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:63) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:97) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:677) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:943) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:831) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736) [kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams doesn't use the regular `consumer` properties.

Did some documentation lead you to believe you needed to set that property when using streams? If so, open a GitHub issue so we can fix it.

It's

```
spring.kafka.streams.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.abc.xyz.Person
```

when using streams.

You don't need a `key.default.type` since you don't have a JSON key serde.

Comment: Thanks Gary. That solved the issue. I was following the doc on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-kafka section 34.3.3 (streams support) and 34.3.4 (kafka Properties) was right after that. I guess I may have misunderstood in the context of streams support section that the properties mentioned apply for streams as well. I also see WARN messages in the application logs when I haven't set the property

    The configuration 'spring.json.value.default.type' was supplied but isn't a known config.

Comment: The boot `...consumer...` properties provision a `ConsumerConfig` map; the `...streams...` properties provision a `StreamsConfig` map; I suggest you open an issue against boot on GitHub if you feel more clarification is needed. Yes, the warning is a bit odd; Kafka allows configuration of a custom deserializer using consumer properties, but then logs a warning that it found an unknown property.